# Reverse Engineering: Tool to read XY-Values out of files

Tags: java, reverse-engineering

I've got to reverse engineer a file containing X/Y values that represent a curve.
Although I know that finally will have to write the converter by myself, i'd be happy to know a windows tool that helps me to find out wether 
- the file consists of Integers, Double or Float values
- the values are big- or little endian
- at which offset the relevant data starts
- and so on...

Does anyone know a tool that can help me to find this out?

Finally, I'll implement the algorithm in Java, so code recommendations also will be welcome!

Thanks in advance

Christoph

Comment: All you need is a hex viewer/editor. If you have software that generates these files, create a file with known values and see what they look like in the file. If you have software that can read those files and show them in a human readable way, edit them with hex editor and see how the program interprets that.

Comment: Dear ArtenB,
Thanks for this tip. The problem is that the files al Mass Spectrometry data files and that they do not contain a few values but hundreds, even if you only start the process for just a second.
I unfortunately do not have easy access to those systems, they are in a productive environemt at my customer's lab, and i can not disturb the process with manipulated data.
Best regards,
Christoph

Comment: You only need few known values to work with. You can try getting 'broken' datasets that are likely to have underexposed/overexposed values. Or you can try getting a data for a reference with known characteristics (hydrogen might work nicely for this purpose) and eyeball the data in the file for the spikes and then by trial and error see if interpreting the data as single/double IEEE754 floating point format produces meaningful results.

Answer (score 0):

A free software you may find useful

- [HxD Editor](http://mh-nexus.de/en/hxd/)